# Jenkins bat command returned value got cut off

Tags: c#, jenkins, tfs, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I was trying to execute is tf command to get the version history from TFS in Jenkins script using the bat command, but the returned strings are trimmed to a certain length. Thus returning incomplete check-in comments. The command I tried is

```
bat(script: "tf history -noprompt -server:http://tfs-myOrganization.com:8080/tfs/vision1 \$/TFS/dev/products/rel/product -version:C120~C150 -recursive -format:brief", returnStdout: true).trim().readLines()
```

This command should return the check-in version, user, date & comments:

```
125   Andy   24/8/2022   fixed this with that and how.
```

But instead the cut-off text returned look something like:

```
125   Andy   24/8/2022   fixed this wi
```

I tried running the command on cmd.exe, the return values are fine. Then I tried to create a .bat file that has this tf command in it then run this .bat file from Jenkins pipeline, the return value still gets cut-off.

Comment: Did you refer to the `tf` documentation? Here's a hint: You're passing the flag `-format:brief`. Consider if there are other format options available and what they might be, using the documentation as a guide.

Comment: Yes I did, the difference between -format:brief and -format:detailed is that the detailed option will return the file changes in the changeset. For my requirement, I just want to retrieve the comment of that check-in and can skip the files changed.
Either way the returned value will still be chopped off. I think it is not about the tf history command, more like on the jenkins side of thing. Because running the tf history command  on standalone cmd.exe and  from Jenkins bat command yields a different results.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one reference which looks similar to above -
can you try it -

```
`bat(script: "tf history -noprompt -server:http://tfs-myOrganization.com:8080/tfs/vision1 \$/TFS/dev/products/rel/product -version:C120~C150 -recursive -format:brief", returnStdout: tr`ue).trim().readLines().drop(1).join(" ")
```

[Jenkins pipeline - variable from a bat command to label, output show full command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64411921/jenkins-pipeline-variable-from-a-bat-command-to-label-output-show-full-comman)

Comment: Yup I have tried that before, the `.drop(1).join(" ")` options are just to omit the executed command at the output. So once the command is executed, only the retrieved value is shown instead of command + retrieved value.